# Returning CSV file from REST webservice as a Stream in C#

Tags: c#, rest, csv, http, stream

I am calling a public REST API to GET a CSV file in my GetStream method, which returns an object of type Stream.

```
public Stream GetStream(object args)
        {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    string responseLine = string.Empty;
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

The previous code was set up to return an XML document, which was serialized from the returned CSV. Now I just need to return the CSV data.

I am creating my Stream object here, which right now is returning XML:

```
Stream baseStream = new MemoryStream();
                    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(baseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    responseXml.WriteTo(tw);
                    tw.Flush();
                    baseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return baseStream;
```

I am unsure how to simply return the CSV data from the response in the Stream. The method is for an adapter in Biztalk, so the CSV will have a schema associated with it and a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by writing the data to the stream using a StreamWriter, flushing it to the Stream and seeking back to the beginning. The resulsts string contains the CSV data from the response. See the code below:

```
 Stream baseStream = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter csvWriter = new StreamWriter(baseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                csvWriter.Write(results);
                csvWriter.Flush();
                baseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Console.WriteLine(baseStream.Length);
                return baseStream;
```